# android device monitor in Telephony Actions

Tags: android, action, telephony

**problem in android device monitor in Telephony Actions**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzaRs.jpg)

Comment: Hi Mohamed! Please edit your question and add more detail about the problem you're experiencing and include the actions you've taken to try and resolve it.

Comment: i uploaded photo explane the problem in

Answer (score 1):

Enable telnet client on your computer.

If you are windows user follow this step:

1.go to control panel

2.go to programs and features

3.click on "turn windows feature on or off" a prompt box will be appear()

4.mark the checkbox of Telnet Client

5.open command prompt and type "telnet localhost port_number" (see [cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C25Vw.png) image) after this connection will be establish.

device monitor in android studio only works for the default emulators. It does not work for genymotion or mobile device.